# Is there an IC for a 32:5 Encoder?

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, encoder

I need a part similar to a [74HC148](http://focus.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74hc148.pdf) 8:3 encoder, but which takes 32 input lines and encodes them to a 5 bit value. I can guarantee that only one of the 32 will be high at a time, so I don't even need the priority feature although it would be a plus. If possible I would like to stay in the 74HC series, or at least compatible chips.

I could implement it with 5 16-input OR gates, but that would require something like 10 chips to implement the entire encoder. It feels like there must be a better way.

Is there a single chip made to do this? Google and digikey searches failed me. Is there a better way to implement it than with a whole bunch of OR gates? I was trying to find a way to combine the 8:3 encoders, but a clever working solution escapes me.

Comment: Yes, I can do this with CPLDs or PICs, but I really would like to stick with simple through-hole logic chips. I am trying to implement as much of my project as possible with pure combinational logic rather than programmable devices.

Comment: Why?  Your result will be bigger and more expensive.  You could make it with all relays too, but that's not a good idea either.

Comment: My project is a custom 8-bit CPU. It has no practical value over than proving that I can make it. I would be thrilled if I could afford enough relays to build a cpu out of them.

Comment: @Olin - CMP wants to [build a CPU](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/17289/simplest-possible-i-o-for-homebrew-8-bit-cpu) from common logic, "as a personal project for no real reason".

Comment: @steven: Right, which he didn't say until after my comment.

Comment: @Olin - There was nothing wrong with your questioning it. I just happened to remember CMP from a previous question about this project. Seems we posted our replies more or less simultaneously.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Page 7 of the very datasheet you linked shows how to cascade the 74HC148 for additional inputs.  [This datasheet](http://focus.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn54ls348.pdf) has a better diagram showing n-device expansion:

[image]

I don't know of any 16/32 input encoders, if you really must do this in a single IC then a simple FPGA / CPLD is your best option.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I missed that. I usually skip over timing diagrams and such that I don't understand, so I must have skimmed past it.

Comment: @CMP - Then learn to understand timing diagrams. It's useful, and if you always skip them, timing issues will bite you in the ass eventually.

Comment: In the scenario where one needs more than 32 inputs, I wonder if the above circuit could be improved by using the A2 out of the lower chip as the enable of the fifth chip in the top row?  It looks like GS from the top chips would have a three-gate delay, and A2 from the bottom chip would likewise have a three-gate delay, thus yielding a total delay path of six gates, versus eight for the EI/EO chain at the top.

Comment: The diagram above is from a datasheet for a '348, not '148. Same basic circuit but has tri-state outputs, and seems to be harder to find. This will create a ton of conflicts if used with the 148.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think a priority encoder 32 bits wide exists, but it should be easy to implement in a **CPLD**. You don't need a 4GB VHDL development system for this, you can write your code in [**Abel**](http://www.latticesemi.com/lit/docs/manuals/abel_ref.pdf), which is a lot easier to start with.

**edit**
Oh, that's right, you're the one with the homebrew CPU! Well, I guess you'll have to stick to 74HCxx then :-). You won't need 16-input gates (don't you mean 32-inputs? Well they don't exist anyway), I would take the outputs of four 74HC148s and feed them to a fifth.

---

**Further reading**
Xilinx appnote: [Using ABEL with Xilinx CPLDs](http://www.eng.tau.ac.il/~guy/Resa99/ABEL_manual.pdf)

Comment: Ok, one of my main concerns is cost. Can you recommend a cheap cpld that is easy to program?

Comment: @CMP - A quick search on Digikey turned up [this CPLD](http://www.latticesemi.com/documents/DS1022.pdf) at USD 3.00 unit price. The functionality is easy, so your basic requirements are the number of I/Os.

Answer (score 0):

There is not one that I know of, but this type of thing is relatively easy in a CPLD.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are single chips for this called microcontrollers.  You need one with at least 37 digital I/O lines but not much processing power.  I don't know (without looking) whether there is one with enough I/O lines in a 44 pin package, as these are often really 40 pin packages with a few redundant pins for the TQFP.  Some newer ones that don't come in DIP anymore might give you all 44 pins to do useful things.  Of course there are 64 pin parts that definitely have enough digital I/O pins.  Something like a PIC 16F1526 should do it.